# Should I use 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu for Google TV development?

Tags: google-tv

I just got a machine with Win7 on it, and would set up dual-boot to Ubuntu 12. My question is that should I choose 32bit or 64bit?  Does it matter?

Comment: The following linked page is a bit dated, but I wonder if it's still true that most Android documentation is based on 32bit Ubuntu as the author claimed?  http://darts.cse.nd.edu:8080/Plone/materials/setting-up-android-development

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the 64bit system. This is because more and more systems are going to the 64bit model and also because you can do both 32bit and 64bit development on a 64bit system.

Answer (score 1):

> https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_setup_android

```
Operating Systems

Windows XP (32-bit), Vista (32- or 64-bit), or Windows 7 (32- or 64-bit)
Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later (x86 only)
Linux (tested on Ubuntu Linux, Lucid Lynx)
GNU C Library (glibc) 2.7 or later is required.
On Ubuntu Linux, version 8.04 or later is required.
64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications.
Eclipse IDE

Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios) or greater
Note: Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) is no longer supported with the latest version of ADT.
Eclipse JDT plugin (included in most Eclipse IDE packages)
JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)
Android Development Tools plugin (recommended)
Not compatible with Gnu Compiler for Java (gcj)
Other development environments

JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)
Apache Ant 1.8 or later
Not compatible with Gnu Compiler for Java (gcj)
Note: Some Linux distributions may include JDK 1.4 or Gnu Compiler for Java, both of which are not supported for Android development.
```

Comment: I don't know if I missed anything on that page, but it only says "Linux OS with KVM," but doesn't give any specific recommendations on what flavor of linux.

Comment: follow the links on that page to Android page and from there on to system requirements page. It lists all the details.

Comment: I edited my answer above to include whats on Android system requirements page.